# What is the syntax for munin eth1 traffic?

Tags: munin

I want my nodes' eth0 and eth1 traffic side by side in a single munin graph, like I have for load. I can't find the variable names for eth0 and eth1. For load it's myserver.com:load.load

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it's probably `if_1` and `if_2`, and `if_err_1` and if `if_err_2` respectively for error traffic.

Have a look at what it's symlinked as in `/etc/munin/plugins` or run `echo fetch|nc localhost 4949` and see what the plugin names return as like that.